# CSS drop-shadow:inset

Tags: css

I have been trying to get the curl shadow effects given [here](http://www.matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html) for box-shadow:inset but have failed to get any thing. Any onw has any clues how I can make it work?

Been trying to get it to work on this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cypft/)**
Changing this to box-shadow:inset and trying variations on transform rotate has not yealded any results:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 13px -3px #000000;

transform: skewY(-12.5deg);
```

I am basically trying to make something like [this](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-178172666/stock-vector-vector-options-background-for-your-business-message.html?src=pp-same_artist-131000138-F6g_DlnaIqdVs-VW_-rSJw-7) for a unordered list in my html/css design.